# Getting a refund from TAP Air Portugal related to COVID-19

Tags: airlines, refunds, portugal, covid-19, tap-portugal

My international conference in Europe this May has been canceled due to the COVID-19. I have a ticket, purchased from TAP air Portugal, from Toronto, Canada to Lisbon. Because it is a non-refundable fare, they don't want to give a refund.

They won't allow me to reschedule later than May 31 of this year. This won't be useful for me.

What options do I have? I'd prefer to get a full refund.

(I am a US citizen if it matters)

Note: They offered to refund just the taxes, which is about 10% of the value. That's not horrible, but I'd rather have the whole thing returned.

Comment: Others with better knowledge may answer, however I’m not sure you have any other options as far as the airline is concerned, given there are currently no official travel restrictions to Portugal AFAIK. Have you checked what your travel insurance covers?

Comment: Your travel insurance *might* cover it if you bought the ticket before the Covid-19 outbreak really got going. If you bought it afterwards, they probably won't.

Comment: You should now that the ticket price also includes fees and taxes the airline has to pay per passenger. You might have a right to get those refunded.

Comment: See my answer for the latest positive news, they'll allow rescheduling until the end of 2020 to any destination `From now on, the reservation change can be made up to 24 hours before the departure of your first flight, rescheduling the new trip to any destination and flying until December 31, 2020.` https://www.flytap.com/en-gb/latest-updates

Comment: I called my credit card and asked for them to give my money back for the tickets. The dispute reason? "The expected goods or services have not been received" I will update this when it becomes final.

Answer (score 32):

Since you bought a non-refundable ticket, the airline does not have to refund you. Travel insurance could pay out if you have “event cancellation” cover. However, since the the Canadian government does not advise against travelling to Portugal, it’s unlikely that most generic policies will pay out.

I would say that your best option is just to wait. It’s *possible* that the flight could be cancelled either due to official travel advisories or reduced demand. In this case, you’ll be eligible for a full refund.

Comment: The travel insurance approach will heavily depend on *when* travel was booked and the insurance was purchased - if both were before the warnings, then travel insurance should pay out.  If it both or either were after, then there are going to be difficulties getting a payout.

Comment: @Moo There are no travel warnings applicable to Portugal at the moment, so if there is a policy, it would have to have been purchased before any hypothetical warning.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer.  Here in NZ, the common theme is that insurance companies are not paying out for Coronavirus related claims if the insurance policy was purchased after January 30th.

Comment: @Moo It presumably varies a bit internationally. In the UK, insurers will pay out if you cancel due to a government travel advisory after you purchased the policy.

Comment: Most travel insurances exclude specifically "pandemic" or "epidemic"

Comment: @Hilmar Most (all?) policies in the UK will pay out if the Foreign Office advises against travel to a region since the policy was taken out. This includes if the reason for the advice is “pandemic”. I can’t speak globally but your sweeping statement is not globally correct either.

Comment: @MJeffryes I hope you’re right, although it seems contradictory for an insurance policy to exclude epidemic and pandemic yet pay out anyway if the FO advises against travel because of an epidemic or pandemic.

Comment: @Traveller It’s not contradictory. Insurance policies do not cover you in places the FCO advises against travelling. It would be contradictory to say that they will not pay out but they also will not cover you.

Comment: @MJeffryes My point was more around 1) whether they’d pay out if I travelled to a country with no travel ban and contracted CoVID-19 while there; and 2) If the WHO officially declared COVID-19 a pandemic, but there remain countries with no cases and no travel ban, would a policy with an explicit epidemic/pandemic exclusion pay out to someone who contracts COVID-19 in one of those countries?

Comment: @MJeffryes "There are no travel warnings applicable to Portugal at the moment" Australia has issued travel warnings for literally every other nation on the planet right now.

Comment: @nick012000 I wrote this answer on 5th March.

Comment: "It’s possible that the flight could be cancelled [...]. In this case, you’ll be eligible for a full refund."  This is no longer true; TAP and many other airlines are now only offering vouchers when they cancel flights.

Comment: @NateEldredge Many of them are only offering vouchers, but it remains to be seen if this is actually legal, particularly for flights falling under EC261/2004.

Answer (score 7):

Try calling the airline and asking for a cancellation. Most airlines are giving a full refund with almost no questions. If they are not giving you a refund, I would say hold on to your ticket for a couple of days and try for a cancellation again. With the corona situation, only looking to get worse, they might realize the intensity of the situation and give you that refund.

Source: Cancelled flights and hotels to/at Germany with 100% refund

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, the airline is now more flexible and generous. Their website has a few errors, perhaps as it's being heavily used with people rebooking?

Answer (score 6):

Today (17th March 2020) the airline have revised their policy which is now much more generous and flexible (at least in terms of rebooking without a change fee or the offer of a voucher).

> Last updated: Tuesday, March 17, 2020, 17:20 / 05:20 PM (WET)
>
> Due to the current situation of Coronavirus (COVID-19), we have
>   extended the possibility of rescheduling your flight, without paying
>   the associated change fee, for any TAP route and for any travel date.
>
> From now on, the reservation change can be made up to 24 hours before
>   the departure of your first flight, rescheduling the new trip to any
>   destination and flying until December 31, 2020.
>
> Alternatively, we fully refund the amount paid for the purchase of the
>   ticket, by issuing a voucher, sent by email, valid for one year, for
>   use on a future journey of your choice. (there's another page of
>   details)

https://www.flytap.com/en-gb/latest-updates

I've just changed my flights from March to October and paid just over 4 euros (5USD) for miscellaneous charges (I'm not fussed about this tiny charge in the circumstances).

Comment: A bit frustrated that they aren't offering full cash refunds like other airlines.

Comment: Are they transferrable?

Comment: @axsvl77 I don't know if the tickets are transferrable, sorry.

Comment: All airlines will go bankrupt very soon. The chances of you taking that flight are... astronomically low unfortunately.

Comment: @JonathanReez The airlines that get propped up by their local governments probably won't. If you're a government that owns a national airline, you probably won't want it to completely go out of business, even if it's not making any profit.

Comment: A quick update, they made numerous scheduling changes to my revised flights planned for October. Meanwhile the event I was due to participate in, in Porto, was changed from in-person to an online-virtual event. So in the end I reluctantly accepted their vouchers as there was no easy way to get a refund. I hope I'll manage to use the vouchers in the 12 months they're valid for. Currently the UK and Portugal aren't welcoming air passengers, so I need to wait for covid to abate.

Answer (score 2):

My husband and I were supposed to go to Portugal on March 5 for 10 days. We spoke with TAP representatives 3 different times in the days leading up to our trip, and they said our ticket was non-refundable, even though COVID-19 was already a global issue and Portugal's health director had assigned a "red alert." We had thought about getting travel insurance, but companies told us that we would not be covered for cancellation, claiming we already knew about COVID-19. My advice: wait to cancel your flight, since TAP might/hopefully offer refunds as things get worse (there are currently 25 confirmed cases in Portugal.) But don't cancel the tickets beyond your scheduled flight, because the penalties are much more costly. I submitted a complaint letter to TAP, but received no confirmation that they received it. And their phone lines are inaccessible at this time. It's a mess!

Comment: I had the same issue with the phone lines - it took a long time to get through.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, the airline have changed their policy and it's now much more generous and flexible. Try again online and good luck, see https://www.flytap.com/en-gb/latest-updates and my answer here in case the web page is updated.

Answer (score 1):

On March 20 we were told that they would deduct $250 per direction (I.e. $500 round trip) and then give the balance as a voucher that had to be used by the end of the year.

Answer (score 1):

I inquired on March 20 too and they said a 70euro per person to cancel a full fare, refundable First class ticket.  I was holding out for a cancellation & full refund.  today, I checked and flight is now cancelled and only a voucher for full amount, with travel started by 12/31/2020.  Now, I wish I had cancelled and paid the $156 for 2 tix.  I still would have received a $700 credit back on my card.

Answer (score -1):

You might try calling the Portugal Embassy and complain to them, the government still owns half of this airline.   I have an SFO to LIS flight in middle of May and hoping to be able to cancel or at least reschedule it.

Comment: Given that its tremendously unlikely that anyone at the Portuguese embassy would take a complaint about TAP Air Portugal (they will almost certainly just tell you to complain to the airline or the aviation regulator), even if they did take a complaint its likely to be filed in a big round container marked "get around to this never", as no one at the embassy is going to have any authority to order TAP to do anything, not will there be a chain of authority to someone who can.

Comment: Did a call to the embassy work?