# Airasia covid refund long time pending

Tags: refunds, airasia

In 2020, I filed two refund requests as suggested by AirAsia's email. However, despite submitting the requests, I have yet to receive the refunds.

The automated response I received indicates that the refunds are still in process. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to reach a human officer at AirAsia currently. I'm becoming increasingly concerned about the status of my refunds.

What steps should I take next?

Has anyone else experienced a similar situation?

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago, why the repeat?

Comment: Your best bet here is to elevate to the aviation oversight of the relevant country. AirAsia will not give you any money without some legal pressure

Comment: @MarkJohnson The moderator have deleted the last message and asked me to post a new one.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, it was posted as a question in an answer field, and as such has to be deleted, not answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covid refund enquiry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161309/covid-refund-enquiry)

Comment: In that question the last lines of Davids answer, or sign up with a "we get your refund for you" service might be relevant.

Comment: @dda Air Portugal is not Air Asia.

Comment: @Hilmar I think elevation might be a choice. I might give it a try. Thanks for your idea.